# How can I extract the following details from watson conversation?

Tags: ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation, watson

I need to extract the flight booking details from user's end. For example, if user says "need a booking for 2 adults and 3 kids" I need to extract the number of adults and kids separately. How can I do this in watson conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate the System entity: `@sys-number`.

But, in your example, the user will types two numeric values, in this case, the values will return one array with the two values:

```
 sys-number[0] = 2
 sys-number[1] = 3
```

And for getting if is the 'adults' or 'kids', you will associate in the order typed by the user. If user types `2 adults and 3 kids`, adults will be *two* and kids will be *three*. So, you can create one new entity with these values (adults, kids) and get the value in the same condition if the user typed your phrase above.

**For example:**

```
Watson: Do you need a book?
condition: @typesUser and @sys-number (with your phrase following your conditions)
response: Ok, you need @sys-number[0] for @typesUser[0] and @sys-number[1] for @typesUser[1]
```

**Images below works perfectly:**

Conditions:

[image]

**Try it out:**

[image]

**Obs.:** @typesUser with `adults` and `kids` values added and the System Entity @sys-number activated.

- See more about dialog conditions [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#dialog-build).
- See more about System entities [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html).

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this solution will work. Suppose if some one write book 2 rooms for 3 adults and 2 kids. here it will fail.
Possible solutions can be: 
1. You can use regex to extract the no of adults or kids
or 
2. Create 2 enitites adults and kids and add values like 2 adults ,1 adults,4 adults. same for kids so that it will automatically identify no of adults and kids.

I just want to say that Create an entity Named @Person and train it with data like 1 Adults,2 Adults,3 Adults and their synonyms. So that if the input is "Book a room for 2 adults" then i will identify 2 Adults in entity and u can use it.Similarly for kids.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Can you edit with details for did that? My answer is based on the question and the example that I saw. And your example can help other's if they have your use case.

Comment: Sorry for delay.